# Custom Module does not appear in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I am required to build a Drupal module that collects data from an API and create a block on the page displaying the data in a specified format. I have downloaded and installed Drupal 8.0 Alpha2.

According to all the scattered un-infomal bits and pieces of information I have gotten I am really struggling to even see what I am trying to do.

Inside modules I have created a directory called custom and inside it placed a folder named "sidebar_currency".

The *.info.yml

I have created this file with its minimum requirements:

```
name: Sidebar Currency module
description: 'Exercise Module.'
package: Custom
hidden: false
type: module
core: 8.x
```

I added the hidden:false entry since I have been getting a "page not found" error.

The routing is as follows:

```
sidebar_currency.content:
  path: '/currency'
    defaults:
      _controller: 'Drupal\sidebar_currency\Controller\SidebarCurrencyController::content'
      _title: 'Sidebar Currency'
      requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

In the controller entry I have tried to add a backslash before the Drupal namespace e.g. '\Drupal\sidebar_currency...'. This did not help at all.

Below is my structure of my module:

```
DRUPAL_INSTALL_DIR
|_ modules
  |_ custom
    |_ sidebar_currency
      }_ src
        |_ Controller
          |_ SidebarCurrencyController.php
      |_ sidebar_currency.info.yml
      |_ sidebar_currency.routing.yml
      |_ composer.json
```

Below is my controller which I would very much expect to see popping up something on my screen.

```
namespace Drupal\sidebar_currency\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class SidebarCurrencyController extends ControllerBase
 {
   public function content()
   {
       return array(
          '#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => $this->t('List of currency'),
        );
     }
  }
```

I am struggling to see this module in my Extend tab on the CMS except for all the rest of modules that have been pre-installed. I have clear all cache from the configuration menu and still cannot see anything.

Do I need to write my code inside sites instead of where it currently is sitting? Can somebody please help and point me to the right direction as to how I am suppose to go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all I need to do in order for my module to show up was to add *module_name*.module file even if it is empty i.e with no contents.

[image]